# A Foundry function-backed column to calculate monthly engine hours over a rolling period

Tags: javascript, typescript, palantir-foundry

I have an Object Set of ‘Engine Hours’ with the below properties:

| Engine# | Date Recorded | Hours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC123 | Jan 21, 2024 | 9,171 |
| ABC123 | Dec 13, 2023 | 9,009 |
| ABC123 | Oct 6, 2023 | 8,936 |
| XYZ456 | Jan 8, 2024 | 5,543 |
| XYZ456 | Nov 1, 2023 | 4,998 |
| XYZ456 | Oct 10, 2023 | 4,002 |

I have a separate Object Set for ‘Engine’ and in an Object Table in Workshop I have added the latest Engine Hours on a given engine by using a column for ‘Linked Objects/Aggregations’ of ‘Engine Hours’ with an ‘Aggregation on Property’ of ‘Maximum’ on ‘Engine Hours’ to display its latest measured hours.

| Engine# | Date Recorded | Latest Hours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC123 | Jan 21, 2024 | 9,171 |
| XYZ456 | Jan 8, 2024 | 5,543 |

However, I would also like a column to show the average monthly use (over a 3-month rolling period). I’ve searched through all the Palantir Learning resources and think this would be a Function-Backed Column but I don’t have any background in TypeScript to code this myself. I have also trawled through this site to see if anyone has coded something similar but can’t find an answer.

Are there any previous examples of a similar Function-Backed Column which I could template to use in this situation?

Many thanks!

Comment: Java is a different language than JavaScript. Why the Java tag? Show the source code or remove the unneeded tags.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you would need a Function to back a derived column in an Object Table in Workshop, for instance.

Below is an example of how to implement it. I've split the logic in 2 functions:

1. One that operates on a "set of object" and return a mapping between each of those object and the value computed (e.g. the average over the 3 last months of...)
2. One function that computes the value of interest for one given object.

There are a few advantages to do this:

- You can then use the function 2 to populate other widgets (like a Metric Card) as you can pass an object and get back the relevant value for that object, without writing the logic a second time
- Function 1 is parallelized by using Promises/asynchronous computation (not a Foundry-specific concept) which allows for a

Limits:

- The [standard enforced limits](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/functions/enforced-limits/#object-set-load-limits) on any function applied, including the number of objects that can be loaded in memory (100k max as of today) and the compute time (30s max as of today).
  This is very unlikely this limit will be hit when function 1 is used, as Workshop can provide a "runtime input" when you configure the derived column in Workshop (instead of providing an Object Set), which will be filled with the objects currently presented on the screen (e.g. the N first objects of the table)

```js
    // import { FunctionsMap } from "@foundry/functions-api";
    // import { Objects, ObjectSet, Engine } from "@foundry/ontology-api";

    /*
    * 1/ This function returns a "FunctionsMap", which acts as a map between one object instance
    * and the value to display in the derived column for that given object instance
    */
    @Function()
    public getDerivedColumn(myEngines: ObjectSet<Engine>): FunctionsMap<Engine, Double>{
        // Initialize the map
        const map = new FunctionsMap<Engine, Double>();

        // Get the object set, load all the object in memory 
        const myEnginesAsArray = myEngines.all();
        // Execute a function for each.
        // Each function will return  Promise which is the result of an asyncronous computation
        const promises = myEnginesAsArray.map(currEngine => this.computeMetric(currEngine));

        // Use Promise.all to wait for all the parallelized async execution to complete
        const allResolvedPromises = await Promise.all(promises);

        // Populate resultMap with bucket and calculated value
        for (let i = 0; i < myEnginesAsArray.length; i++) {
            map.set(myEnginesAsArray[i], allResolvedPromises[i]);
        }

        return map;
    }


    /* 2/ Simple function that gets the value for one given object */
    @Function()
    public async computeMetric(currentEngine : Engine): Promise<Double> {
        // Pivoting from one Object Type to another, see https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/functions/api-objects-links/#link-types
        const enginesHours: ObjectSet<EngineHours> = currentEngine.searchAroundEnginesHours();
        // Filtering to the relevant dates, see https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/functions/api-object-sets/#filtering
        const ThreeMonthsAgo = LocalDate.now().minusMonths(3);
        const relevantEnginesHours : ObjectSet<EngineHours> = enginesHours.filter(engineHour => engineHour.dateRecorded.range(ThreeMonthsAgo, LocalDate.now()))
        // Aggregating the relevant objects
        const sumValue = relevantEnginesHours.average(o => o.valueProperty);
        return sumValue;
    }
```

Note: This exact code is untested, but should be very close to what you need.

[Docs for function-backed column in Workshop](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/workshop/widgets-object-table/#function-backed-columns)

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried the code as you wrote it and the second function appears to be causing issues. The error was: Property searchAroundEnginesHours does not exist on type Engine.

Comment: I changed the code to:
  
        let enginesHours = Objects.search()
                            .engine([currentEngine])
                            .searchAroundEnginesHours()
                            .orderBy(Hours => Hours.Hours.desc())
                            .take(12)
                           
       let latestMeasurement = enginesHours[0].Hours; 
       let twelfthMeasurement = enginesHours[Math.max(12)].Hours;
       let average4WeekUse = (latestMeasurement - twelfthMeasurement) /3;
       return average4WeekUse;
    }
}

Comment: But this results in the errors:
• latestMeasurement is possibly undefined
• TwelfthMeasurement is possible undefined – these make me think the array is empty?
• Await expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules

Comment: The issues you are facing are typescript errors, which depends and relates to the properties on your Ontology Objects. for instant "latestMeasurement" is not guaranteed to have a value (hence why it can be "undefined", think of it like a "null"). 
So you need to provide a default value, for instance:
const var = blabla.latestMeasurement ?? 0.0

Comment: That worked! I also had to tweak the searchAround to const enginesHours = Objects.search().Engine([currentEngine]).searchAroundEnginesHours();.....................Thanks!